# Where is Table Manager in QGIS 1.7.x?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I would like to ask you, if is available funcionality like "Table Manager" for **QGIS 1.7.x**?
I need to **move fields in attribute table** and then save changes.

I don't see "Table Manager" or something like that in available plugins.

Comment: how about download and install new version of qgis? It is any problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is available - I have it on my copy of QGIS 1.7.x. Make sure you are getting plugins for all repositories.

Plugins -> Fetch Python Plugins...

Perhaps you are looking under Plugins -> Manage Plugins, which only shows already-installed plugins.